# Use AngularJS to integrate with DOJO styleseet whithout widget function.

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, dojo

Does anyone knows about a practical way to integrate AngularJS with DOJO stylesheet but DOJO widget function? Currently I'm trying to code with AngularJS but the page will be passed by DOJO web site. So that I need to make my web page looks like the previous one to keep its own consistency CSS. Hope someone is going give me a great tip.

Comment: So what exactly are you trying? What do you need the Dojo stylesheet for if widgets should not work?

Comment: I need to use DOJO claro.css for my AngularJS page. But I don't want to individually add classes for each elements.